# Home to make a Multi Level Field Dependency in Admin Form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, layout, adminform

I have 3 Field

- type
- Display On
- Container

[image]

the visibility of [Display on , container] depends on value of type field

value of [container] depends on value of [Display on ] on field

I have tried this

```
<field name="slider_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\ProductType</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName/js/form/element/options</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">slider_type</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="slider_location">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Location</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Display On</item>

                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">slider_location</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName/js/form/element/containers</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Here is My `Options.js`

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            var value=this._super().initialValue; 
            console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);
            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_location');
            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_postion');
            if (value=='new' || value=='best-seller' || value=='featured' || value=='mostviewed') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
            } else {
                field1.hide();
                field2.hide();
            }



            return this._super();
        },
        onUpdate: function (value) { 
            console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);

            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_postion');
            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_location');
            if (value=='new' || value=='best-seller' || value=='featured' || value=='mostviewed') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
            } else {
                field1.hide();
                field2.hide();
            }



            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

I am getting an error in `options.js`

> TypeError: field1 is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Why did you call the parent method twice? Try the following way, maybe will fix:

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var value=this.value(); 
            console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);
            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_location');
            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_postion');
            if (value=='new' || value=='best-seller' || value=='featured' || value=='mostviewed') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
            } else {
                field1.hide();
                field2.hide();
            }



            return this;
        },
        onUpdate: function (value) { 
            console.log('Selected Value: ' + value);

            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_postion');
            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = slider_location');
            if (value=='new' || value=='best-seller' || value=='featured' || value=='mostviewed') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
            } else {
                field1.hide();
                field2.hide();
            }



            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this Still getting same errot

Comment: Did you clear your browser js cache?

Comment: yes sir i clear var/ pub/static and generated/ and run set:upgrade as well

Comment: whenever i put  `<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_ModuleName/js/form/element/containers</item>
                </item>` in the sliderpostion field it gives me error otherwise its working well in show/hide funtionality